# RoR tutorial (Michael Hartl) URI::InvalidURIError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, uri, railstutorial.org

I am following the RoR tutorial by Michael Hartl. Currently on chapter 3. My problem is that I don't get the view I see at https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages#fig-raw_home_view.

Instead I'm seeing a

[image]

The URL I'm trying to enter is: `"localhost:3000/static_pages/help"`. 
The `application.html.erb` looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>SampleApp</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm still a rookie so really don't know what to do.

Comment: You have a empty controller action help and in your view you just have some simple statement....then you are trying to access your help action? Please share the URL that you are trying to access which results in this error and also if theirs some other scenario that you are trying to do...

Comment: Your error says you have an issue in your `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` file, so please post that.  Looks like you have a stray `]` somewhere...?

Comment: @SnehaT The URL that i'm trying to acces is: http://localhost:3000/static_pages/help. I get the same error when i'm visiting http://localhost:3000/static_pages/home.

Comment: @PaulFioravanti  Image where you can see the file => https://postimg.org/image/5iikl3ok7/

Comment: @gregletic that image 404s.  Please don't post images but rather copy and paste your code into an edit to your question.

Comment: @PaulFioravanti My apologies, i'm still new at this but thanks for the advice. I edited the code in my question

Comment: Hmmm... your `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` file doesn't seem to have issues, so you may want to consider posting your `StaticPagesController` in an edit to your question, or pushing the code that you have up to a Github repository and sharing the link here.

Comment: @PaulFioravanti I've pushed the project to a git repo: https://github.com/gregsar/sampple_app_stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with your app's name.  To the right of `Rails.root` in your image, you can see that your app's name is:

```
sample_app]
```

`Rails.root` is the path to your application's directory, and it's used as the base path for locating all the files in your project.

The `Rails.root` is used in the url marked `bad URI`. The url is illegal because urls can only contain certain characters, and a bracket isn't one of them.

Your web browser is trying to request a css file that is specified in the application layout, and rails converts the request url to a local file url using the Rails.root.  Unfortunately, Rails doesn't even bother looking for the file--instead Rails stops when it sees an illegal character in the url and throws an error.

Comment: I named my app indeed: sample_app]. It was a typo but since I'm working on a tutorial I thought it wouldn't be a problem so I didn't changed it.

Comment: @gregletic, The error is actually saying that the bracket is an illegal character in a url.  As a result, when Rails creates file urls from Rails.root, you get an invalid url error.

Comment: Aaah thank you. Didn't quite get the error message but you solved my problem. Thank you!